# JSONDecodeError: Extra data

Tags: python, json

I'm trying to convert a payload into json but I get the a JSONDecodeError: Extra data error.
I need them to be 3 separate payloads to be posted to an API.

"data": {
"CustomerID": "15263",
"Timestamp": "2023-07-28T17:08:23Z",
"Status": "networkOk"
}

"data": {
"CustomerID": "15891",
"Timestamp": "2023-07-28T17:08:23Z",
"Status": "networkOk"
}

"data": {
"CustomerID": "16986",
"Timestamp": "2023-07-28T17:08:23Z",
"Status": "networkOk"
}

```
import json

payload= '{"CustomerID":"15263","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"},"1":{"CustomerID":"15891","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"},"2":{"CustomerID":"16986","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"}'

payload = json.loads(payload)

payload = json.dumps({"data":payload})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this example to "split" the string into 3 dictionaries. But I recommend fixing how the string is made (to make it correct Json):

```py
import json

payload = '{"CustomerID":"15263","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"},"1":{"CustomerID":"15891","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"},"2":{"CustomerID":"16986","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"}'

# "quick-and-dirty" way to make json.loads work
payload = json.loads('{"0":' + payload + "}")

for v in payload.values():
    print(v)
```

Prints:

```py
{'CustomerID': '15263', 'Timestamp': '2023-07-28T15:12:48Z', 'Status': 'networkRisk'}
{'CustomerID': '15891', 'Timestamp': '2023-07-28T15:12:48Z', 'Status': 'networkRisk'}
{'CustomerID': '16986', 'Timestamp': '2023-07-28T15:12:48Z', 'Status': 'networkRisk'}
```

Answer (score 1):

Change the structure and format of the payload_JSON to a list of objects in a string.

When this string is loaded using json.loads(), it is converted into a list of Python dictionaries. Next, in the for loop, each object in the list is extracted and sent as a separate JSON payload to the API server.

```
import json

# The JSON payload as an array of objects
payload_json = '[{"CustomerID":"15263","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"},' \
               '{"CustomerID":"15891","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"},' \
               '{"CustomerID":"16986","Timestamp":"2023-07-28T15:12:48Z","Status":"networkRisk"}]'

# Load the JSON data as a list of dictionaries
payload_list = json.loads(payload_json)

# Iterate through each data object and create separate payloads
for index, data in enumerate(payload_list):
    payload = json.dumps({"data": data})
    # Here, you can post the payload to the API
    print(f"Payload {index+1}: {payload}")
```

this is the output:

```
Payload 1: {"data": {"CustomerID": "15263", "Timestamp": "2023-07-28T15:12:48Z", "Status": "networkRisk"}}
Payload 2: {"data": {"CustomerID": "15891", "Timestamp": "2023-07-28T15:12:48Z", "Status": "networkRisk"}}
Payload 3: {"data": {"CustomerID": "16986", "Timestamp": "2023-07-28T15:12:48Z", "Status": "networkRisk"}}
```